# How Does Mercurial Communicate Changes Between Clients?

Tags: mercurial

Forgive me if this question sounds ridiculously naive, but I don't seem to be able to find a straightforward answer to this anywhere.

I am considering using Mercurial for source control on a small (2-3 developers) project.  I like the idea of not having to subscribe to a central repository, and I like that everyone effectively has a complete copy of the project.  What I don't understand is how the Mercurial clients communicate changes to each other.  Does it require opening a specific port or something similar?

Any pointers to help on Mercurial or comments from people who have used it would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial can access remote repositories in a number of ways. The main ones are:

- File access (i.e. look at the repo at this path)
- HTTP / HTTPS (i.e. look at the repo being served at this web address)
- SSH (i.e. log into this machine / user, and look at the repo at this path)

The first only really works if your team is all working on a shared file-system, but is also useful if you personally have multiple clones that you want to move information between.

HTTP is how you would access something like Bitbucket, or some other "available to all" server. You can set-up a temporary server on a machine with the command `hg serve`, and that's useful if you need to share with a colleague quickly and don't care about security, but normally HTTP Mercurial servers sit behind Apache, or some other web server software.

An SSH based set-up is just a machine running an SSH server which has Mercurial installed. Mercurial logs on to the machine, and invokes `hg` remotely. The local `hg` and the remote `hg` then talk over the link. Very easy to set-up in my opinion. Credentials are all handled in normal SSH ways.

Further reading:[Publishing Repositories](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories)